# direct and indirect calls/jumps in output of objdump

Tags: x86, branch, disassembly

Looking at the output of `objdump -d ELFfile`, I could not distinguish between direct and indirect Jumps/calls. Any suggestions?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9223756/what-does-an-asterisk-before-an-address-mean-in-x86-64-att-assembly

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Indirect calls and jumps have a `*` after the instruction and before the location like in `callq *%r13` and `jmpq *0x204d8a(%rip)`.

I'll show two real examples from my x86-64 Linux machine:

1. **qsort()** in the C standard library calling the user-supplied comparison function
2. A dynamically linked executable calling **strcmp()**

The **qsort()** implementation in GLIBC actually calls different sort algorithms depending on input size. One such implementation is **msort_with_tmp()** in **/lib64/libc.so.6**:

```
0000003cbde37d70 <msort_with_tmp.part.0>:
  <...>
  3cbde37dd6:   4c 8b 68 10             mov    0x10(%rax),%r13
  <...>
  3cbde37e2f:   41 ff d5                callq  *%r13
```

The code snippet above moves the address of the comparison function into **R13** and eventually does an indirect call.

For a dynamically linked executable calling **strcmp()**, I'll use **/bin/true** as an example. All calls to **strcmp()** in the main executable gets translated into a call to the PLT stub, **strcmp@plt**:

```
$ gdb /bin/true
(gdb) disassemble 'strcmp@plt'
0x401350 <+0>:  ff 25 8a 4d 20 00 jmpq  *0x204d8a(%rip) # 0x6060e0 <strcmp@got.plt>
0x401356 <+6>:  68 19 00 00 00    pushq $0x19
0x40135b <+11>: e9 50 fe ff ff    jmpq  0x4011b0
```

In the first instruction, **0x204d8a(%rip)** uses **RIP** relative addressing to locate **strcmp@got.plt**.

If we try to inspect what value **strcmp@got.plt** holds at runtime:

```
(gdb) break *0x401350
(gdb) run --XXX
Breakpoint 1, 0x0000000000401350 in strcmp@plt ()

(gdb) p/a 'strcmp@got.plt'
$1 = 0x3cbdf2fbe0 <__strcmp_sse42>
(gdb) break *0x3cbdf2fbe0
Breakpoint 2 at 0x3cbdf2fbe0: file ../sysdeps/x86_64/multiarch/strcmp-sse42.S, line 128.
(gdb) continue 
Continuing.

Breakpoint 2, __strcmp_sse42 ()
    at ../sysdeps/x86_64/multiarch/strcmp-sse42.S:128
128     mov %esi, %ecx
```

We see that **strcmp@got.plt** points to **__strcmp_sse42()** in **/usr/lib64/libc.so.6**.

Thus the first indirect jump we met, **jmpq   *0x204d8a(%rip)** in **strcmp@plt**, ends up jumping to **__strcmp_sse42()**. This is the [STT_GNU_IFUNC](http://vger.kernel.org/~davem/cgi-bin/X_blog.cgi/2010/02/07) mechanism in action. It uses the dynamic linker to find the most suitable **strcmp()** variant at runtime based on CPU capabilities.

Answer (score 3):

On x86-64 CPUs, the call and jump instructions are implicitly %rip relative.

So the relevant modes are:

```
jmpq  $6  # Direct, relative: Jump to %rip+0x6
jmpq  *$6 # Direct, absolute: Jump to 0x6
jmpq  %r13  # Indirect, relative: Jump to %rip+%r13
jmpq  *%r13 # Indirect, absolute: Jump to %r13. Aka "movq %r13, %rip"
```

And then the doubly indirect modes:

```
jmpq 0x20(%r13) # Jump to %rip + *(%r13 + 0x20).
jmpq *0x20(%r13) # Jump to *(%r13 + 0x20)
```

The last addressing mode is very commonly seen in C++ disassembly as

```
callq *0x20(%r13)
```

where %r13 contains the address of a vtable. So it looks up the entry in the vtable at offset 0x20 and then calls the function pointed to by that entry.
It's always absolute mode (i.e. not %rip relative) as the vtable is used from multiple call sites so %rip relative wouldn't make any sense.