# How to understand the output of objdump, about indirect jmp?

Tags: linux, kernel, reverse-engineering, x86-64, disassembly

When objdump -S my_program, usually I can see the following indirect jmp instruction, which is typically used for switch/case jump table:

`ffffffff802e04d3:       ff 24 d5 38 2e 10 81    jmpq   *-0x7eefd1c8(,%rdx,8)`

How to understand the address `-0x7eefd1c8`? It means the table's base address is `0xffffffff802e04d3 - 0x7eefd1c8`?

Also, how can I get `-0x7eefd1c8` from `ff 24 d5 38 2e 10 81`?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What does this x86-64 assembly line do?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9223756/what-does-this-x86-64-assembly-line-do)

Comment: That question does not answer:  How to get `-0x7eefd1c8` from `ff 24 d5 38 2e 10 81`. It is a decoding issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> decoding issue

Than you have to look at [Intel Development Manuals](http://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/processors/architectures-software-developer-manuals.html)

- `ff` is JMP opcode (Jump near, absolute indirect) [1]
- `24` is a *ModR/M* byte [2] which means that *SIB* byte goes after it (JMP opcode has only one operand, so register field is ignored)
- `d5` is a *SIB* byte [2] which means that *disp32* goes after that, `Scale = 8` and `Index = %rdx` (in 32-bit mode, Index should be `%edx`) with no base.
- `38 2e 10 81` is a 4-byte *disp32* operand. If you encode it as double word, you will get `0x81102e38` note that highest bit is set to `1`. It is a sign bit meaning that value is encoded in *Two’s Complement Encoding* [3].

Converting from two's complement gives us expected number:

```
>>> print hex(0x81102e38 - (1 << 32))
-0x7eefd1c8
```

When processor executes that instruction in 64-bit mode, it reads 8 bytes from `0xffffffff81102e38 + (%rdx * 8)` (original number is sign-extended) and puts that quad word into `%rip` [4].

References to manuals:

1. Vol.2A, section *3.2 INSTRUCTIONS (A-M)*, page *3-440*
2. Vol 2, section *2.1.5 Addressing-Mode Encoding of ModR/M and SIB Bytes*, pages *2-6..2-7*
3. Vol 1, section *4.2.1.2 Signed Integers*, page *4-4*
4. Vol 2, section *2.2.1.3 Displacement*, page *2-11*