# What does call *(%rax, %rcx,8) mean in a loop? Why do RAX and RCX change afterwards?

Tags: assembly, x86-64, reverse-engineering, disassembly, att

I have this function pointer and this code:

```
0x0000555555556e80 <+0>:     push   %rbp
0x0000555555556e81 <+1>:     mov    %rsp,%rbp
0x0000555555556e84 <+4>:     sub    $0x10,%rsp
0x0000555555556e88 <+8>:     movl   $0x0,-0x4(%rbp)
0x0000555555556e8f <+15>:    movslq -0x4(%rbp),%rcx
0x0000555555556e93 <+19>:    lea    0x7406(%rip),%rax        # 0x55555555e2a0 <init_functions>
0x0000555555556e9a <+26>:    cmpq   $0x0,(%rax,%rcx,8)
0x0000555555556e9f <+31>:    je     0x555555556ec1 <initialize_bomb+65>
0x0000555555556ea5 <+37>:    movslq -0x4(%rbp),%rcx
0x0000555555556ea9 <+41>:    lea    0x73f0(%rip),%rax        # 0x55555555e2a0 <init_functions>
0x0000555555556eb0 <+48>:    call   *(%rax,%rcx,8)
0x0000555555556eb3 <+51>:    mov    -0x4(%rbp),%eax
0x0000555555556eb6 <+54>:    add    $0x1,%eax
0x0000555555556eb9 <+57>:    mov    %eax,-0x4(%rbp)
0x0000555555556ebc <+60>:    jmp    0x555555556e8f <initialize_bomb+15>
0x0000555555556ec1 <+65>:    add    $0x10,%rsp
0x0000555555556ec5 <+69>:    pop    %rbp
0x0000555555556ec6 <+70>:    ret
```

It's a loop that iterates 11 times, and I really don't know how to handle the function pointer. When there's the `call *(%rax,%rcx,8)`, the two registers involved (RAX and RCX) change but I don't understand how or why, since I don't know what happens in that call...

I can't put breakpoints. I don't know what to do.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`call *address` loads a function pointer from memory into RIP, using standard AT&T syntax for an addressing mode (or register name) following the `*`.  See *[What does an asterisk * before an address mean in x86-64 AT&T assembly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9223756/what-does-an-asterisk-before-an-address-mean-in-x86-64-att-assembly)*  So this pushes a return address then loads a new RIP from the address `[rax + rcx*8]`.

The `call *foo` syntax (EIP/RIP = dword/qword loaded from memory at `foo`, memory-indirect) has an asterisk to disambiguate from `call foo` (RIP = address of `foo`, a direct `call rell32`), in case you were using just a bare symbol name as the addressing mode.

In 64-bit mode you'd normally use `call *foo(%rip)` for a static function pointer that wasn't in an array, but AT&T syntax was designed long before x86-64 existed, and 64-bit mode would still have that ambiguity.  (In all other cases, GAS will warn if you leave out the `*`, and infer that you meant an indirect jump/call if you write something like `call (%rax)` or `call %rax`.)

---

RAX and RCX are call-clobbered so it's normal they don't keep their value; notice how their values before `call` come from an LEA and a load from a local on the stack.  (*[What registers are preserved through a linux x86-64 function call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18024672/what-registers-are-preserved-through-a-linux-x86-64-function-call)*)

If you want to see what functions are called, use GDB `stepi` (aka `si`) to single-step into the call.  (Put a breakpoint somewhere in this function so you can single step from there.)

---

**If you want to understand the loop, look at the code surrounding the `call`.**

A RIP-relative LEA puts a constant address into RAX; as fjs points out, there's a symbol name `init_functions`.

RCX is loaded from a local var on the stack, with sign-extension from 32-bit to 64.  Looking at the surrounding code, this is clearly a loop counter, initialized to zero earlier in the function.  Presumably an `int`.

Before the call, the same array indexing is done to check if it's a NULL pointer.  This is clearly [debug-mode compiler output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53366394/why-does-clang-produce-inefficient-asm-with-o0-for-this-simple-floating-point), where each C statement is compiled to a separate block of asm.  That means you only have to look locally to see what a block is doing in isolation, but it leads to much more code than would be necessary, e.g. two accesses to the array and redoing sign-extension of the loop counter each time.

Some things like this are simple enough that the whole loop is easy to follow in an optimized build.  Well, easy enough; GCC does rotate the loop so the condition can be at the bottom, partially peeling it.  And checks the first condition before saving RBX (shrink-wrap optimization) which it uses to hold a pointer into the array. (Instead of using a pointer and separate integer index).

```
extern void (*init_functions[])();

void init(){
    for(int i=0 ; init_functions[i]  ; i++) 
        init_functions[i]();
}
```

[Godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/qcEEYxvEe)

```
init():
        movq    init_functions(%rip), %rax   # partially peeled first iteration
        testq   %rax, %rax
        je      .L9
        pushq   %rbx
        leaq    8+init_functions(%rip), %rbx      # fptr = &init_functions[1]
          # enter the loop with RAX holding first array entry
.L3:                         # do{
        call    *%rax
        movq    (%rbx), %rax    # load the next 
        addq    $8, %rbx        # fptr++
        testq   %rax, %rax      # and test it
        jne     .L3          # }while( *fptr != 0 )
        popq    %rbx
        ret
.L9:
        ret         # silly compiler, no need for tail duplication here.
```

Comment: `leaq    8+init_functions(%rip), %rbx      # fptr = &init_functions[0]` Wouldn't that be `[1]`?

Comment: @JosephSible-ReinstateMonica: Yes, thanks, forgot about the +8 while I was commenting that line, was thinking about whether to talk about a simplified version using pointers IIRC.

Answer (score 2):

The comment after this instruction tells you the value of rax:
`<+41>:    lea    0x73f0(%rip),%rax        # 0x55555555e2a0 <init_functions>`

Regarding %rcx, look at your disassembly code everywhere you either load from or store to -0x4(%rbp). It's a local variable used as the loop counter, initialized as 0 and incremented by 1 every iteration. The code could well look like this: `for(int idx=0; init_functions[idx]!=NULL; ++idx) init_functions[idx]();` The function pointers are each 8 bytes long, so that why you call into `%rax + 0x8 * %rcx`

(Thanks to Peter Cordes' suggestion on the meaning of %rcx.)

Comment: Close, but RCX isn't loaded from a function arg.  It's *below* the frame pointer (RBP) in this debug-mode compiler output; it's a local var, a loop counter initialized with `movl   $0x0,-0x4(%rbp)` and updated inside the loop.  Also used as the loop-exit condition, when it finds a NULL pointer.  (The code would be easier to follow in an optimized build, but it's `for(int i=0 ; init_functions[i] != NULL ; i++) init_functions[i]();` done with two accesses to the array and redoing sign-extension of `i` each time.  https://godbolt.org/z/hb78MYhqK)

Comment: Feel free to edit your answer to be correct instead of just saying to see comments, that's why I commented.  Note that the first six function args are passed in registers, so no, function args aren't usually passed on the stack.  The LEA part is right.

Answer (score 0):

The jump address is %rax+%rcx*8, whatever that is in your circumstance. And note that %rax is %rip-relative and %rcx is getting loaded with something from the stack.