# Global assembly in Rust/LLVM: "jmp %rax" is not allowed but the syntax is fine in GAS (mnemonic without a size suffix)

Tags: assembly, rust, x86, gnu-assembler

I noticed that, unlike *GNU as* (GAS), the LLVM-internal assembler, which is used by Rust, doesn't allow using `jmp %rax`. The compiler errors with "mnemonic without a size suffix". If I try adding a size suffix like this `jmpq %rax`, it doesn't work either.

Minimal reproducer:

```rust
core::arch::global_asm!(
        "foo:",
        "mov $ffffffff88000000, %rax",
        "jmp %rax"
    , options(att_syntax));

fn main() {
}
```

When I compile this assembly code with GAS, `objdump` shows `jmpq *%rax`.

Comment: It's not totally "fine" in GAS, it warns about an indirect jump used without `*`.  As explained in [What does an asterisk \* before an address mean in x86-64 AT&T assembly?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9223756), it disambiguates `jmp foo` (RIP = foo, `jmp rel32`) from `jmp *foo` (absolute addressing mode for a memory-indirect jump)

Comment: It would probably be good if LLVM's error message was more helpful, suggesting you might have meant to use a `*`.

Answer (score 2):

There are subtle differences between GAS and LLVM's internal assembler. GAS seems to allow more "sloppiness" and LLVM is more precisely.

I don't know what's the meaning of it, but changing the line to `jmp *%rax` (with *) solves the issue.

Comment: The `*` distinguishes direct from indirect jumps by making the jump look like it would [on a PDP-11](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42250270/417501).